# Error in code: two ViewController with PDF file…

Tags: ios, pdf

I have a ViewController with a PDF file inside it. Now, I have another ViewController and want to integrate a PDF file, too.

But I get some errors. This is the code:

```
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self refresh:self];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plan" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_ImageInWebView loadRequest:request];
    [_ImageInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plan" ofType:@"pdf"]; (Error: Redefinition of 'path')
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; (Error: Redefinition of 'url')
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; (Error: Redefinition of 'request')
    [_PDFInWebView loadRequest:request];
    [_PDFInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myBotton.layer.borderWidth =2.0f;
    _myBotton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
}
```

I wrote the error message I get in brackets behind the code.
What can I do to solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the same variables twice within one method.

Why not change that second block of code to just reuse the already declared variables?

e.g., this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plan" ofType:@"pdf"]; (Error: Redefinition of 'path')
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; (Error: Redefinition of 'url')
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; (Error: Redefinition of 'request')
[_PDFInWebView loadRequest:request];
[_PDFInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

becomes

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plan" ofType:@"pdf"];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[_PDFInWebView loadRequest:request];
[_PDFInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: I didn‘t now how to. Thank you very much. It works now perfekt. You are great.

Comment: Other question: How can I save a local PDF file (to iBooks or an other PDF reader) by clicking a button?

Comment: try asking a new question and let's see how fast I (or somebody else) can answer it...

Comment: I tried, but I get this message: "You can only post once every 90 minutes."
Can't you say me the code please?